# Changing the innerHTML of a class referenced in many locations

Tags: javascript, html

My question might be very simple but I'm stumped. How can I change for example the color of the text of all three of the `<p>` tags? As it is, it only changes the first one it sees.

```
<html>

<script "text/JavaScript">

function myFunction() {

document.querySelectorAll('p').style.color = 'red';
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction();">Click</button>

<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
<p>Line 3</p>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over it to set the color of individual `<p>`

Comment: What do you mean iterate over it?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList, not a single element, so you have to iterate

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a collection of all matched elements, you need to iterate over the collection and set styles for each element

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/

Comment: I posted an answer below that gives you the exact function you need.  You can use `querySelectorAll` in place of `getElementsByTagName` if you wish - same result though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```